# Quotient of noncommutative algebra

Tags: modules, ideals, algebras

Let $R=k\langle x,y,z \rangle$ be the non-commutative algebra in $3$ variables. Let $I$ be the ideal defined by the relations $xy-yx,yz-zy,xz-zx$. How to show formally that $R/I$ is the polynomial ring $k[x,y,z]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following $k$ algebra morphism
$$\psi:k\langle X,Y,Z\rangle\longrightarrow k[x,y,z] $$
$$X\mapsto x$$
$$Y\mapsto y$$
$$Z\mapsto z$$

then show that $ker \psi= I$, and by the first isomorphism theorem (of rings)  we are done.